# How to save data from firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to get data to the app from Firebase Realtime Database.
How is a button which loads data from db looks like:

```java
load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            database.child(emailString).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();

                                        Russian_Reno = snapshot.child("russian_reno").getValue(Integer.class);
                                        T_18_1927 = snapshot.child("T_18_1927").getValue(Integer.class);

                                        PreferenceConfig.RussianReno(getApplicationContext(), Russian_Reno);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_18_1927(getApplicationContext(), T_18_1927);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_18_1929(getApplicationContext(), T_18_1929);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_18_1930(getApplicationContext(), T_18_1930);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_18M(getApplicationContext(), T_18M);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_20(getApplicationContext(), T_20);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26_1931(getApplicationContext(), T_26_1931);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26_1932(getApplicationContext(), T_26_1932);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26_1933(getApplicationContext(), T_26_1933);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26_1936(getApplicationContext(), T_26_1936);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26_1938(getApplicationContext(), T_26_1938);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26_1939(getApplicationContext(), T_26_1939);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26PT(getApplicationContext(), T_26PT);

                                        PreferenceConfig.TY_26_TT_26(getApplicationContext(), TY_26_TT_26);

                                        PreferenceConfig.TY_132_TT_131(getApplicationContext(), TY_132_TT_131);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26A(getApplicationContext(), T_26A);

                                        PreferenceConfig.XT_26(getApplicationContext(), xT_26);

                                        PreferenceConfig.XT_130(getApplicationContext(), xT_130);

                                        PreferenceConfig.XT_133(getApplicationContext(), xT_133);

                                        PreferenceConfig.XT_134(getApplicationContext(), xT_134);

                                        PreferenceConfig.CT_26(getApplicationContext(), ct_26);

                                        PreferenceConfig.T_26_T(getApplicationContext(), T_26_T);

                                        PreferenceConfig.BT_1(getApplicationContext(), bt_1);

                                        PreferenceConfig.M1930(getApplicationContext(), m1930);

                                        
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Log.d("Firebase", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!

                                    }

                                }
                            });

                                                                           }


                        });}}});
```

How we can see, i have child email and in this child i have data: email.
Here is JSON file from db:

```json
{
  "mail@gmailcom": {
    "battles": 5000,
    "broneboynie": 7000,
    "bt_1": 500,
    "bt_2": 0,
    "bt_2_H": 0,
    "bt_2_IS": 0,
    "bt_2_P": 0,
    "bt_2_PP": 0,
    "bt_2_PY": 0,
    "bt_2_PY_B_SH_u": 0,
    "bt_2_S": 0,
    "bt_3": 0,
    "bt_4": 0,
    "bt_5": 0,
    "bt_5_A": 0,
    "bt_5_B_2": 0,
    "bt_5_IS": 0,
    "bt_5_PT": 0,
    "bt_5_Px": 0,
    "bt_6": 0,
    "bt_7": 0,
    
  },
  "mail1212@gmailcom": {
    "battles": 5000,
    "broneboynie": 7000,
    "bt_1": 500,
    "bt_2": 0,
    "bt_2_H": 0,
    "bt_2_IS": 900,
    "bt_2_P": 0,
    "bt_2_PP": 0,
    "bt_2_PY": 0,
    "bt_2_PY_B_SH_u": 0,
    "bt_2_S": 0,
    "bt_3": 0,
    "bt_4": 0,
    "bt_5": 0,
    "bt_5_A": 0,
    "bt_5_B_2": 0,
    "bt_5_IS": 0,
    "bt_5_PT": 0,
    "bt_5_Px": 0,
    "bt_6": 0,
    "bt_7": 0,

}
```

I have same names of variables which in `user` class and in this class:

```java
//this class
private int battles;
private String email;
```

User class, it in another package

```java
//User class
package anoterPagkage;
public class User {
private int battles;
private String email;
public String getemail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setemail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
public int getBattles() {
        return battles;
    }

    public void setBattles(int battles) {
        this.battles = battles;
    }
```

Here is PreferenceConfig class, which save data. (you can see this class in code, where i trying save data to this class)

```java
public class PreferenceConfig {
    private static final String MY_PREFERENCE_NAME = "com.ccs.example";
    public static final String BATTLES = "battles";
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";

public static void registerPref(Context context, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public static void unregisterPref(Context context, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

 public static void email(Context context, String count) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(EMAIL, count);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String emailString(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return pref.getString(EMAIL,"");
    }

public static void battles(Context context, int count) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt(BATTLES, count);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static int battlesInt(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return pref.getInt(BATTLES, 0);
    }
}
```

here photo of db:
[image]

How looks button which save data to db:

```
User user = new User();

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String a = emailString.replace(".", "");
                if(database.child(a)==null) {
                    user.setrussian_reno(Russian_Reno);
                    user.setT_18_1927(T_18_1927);
                    user.setT_18_1929(T_18_1929);
                    user.setT_18_1930(T_18_1930);
                    user.setT_18m(T_18M);
                    user.setT_20(T_20);
                    user.setT_26_1931(T_26_1931);
                    user.setT_26_1932(T_26_1932);
                    user.setT_26_1933(T_26_1933);
                    user.setT_26_1936(T_26_1936);
                    user.setT_26_1938(T_26_1938);
                    user.setT_26_1939(T_26_1939);
                    user.setT_26PT(T_26PT);
                    user.setty_26_tt_26(TY_26_TT_26);
                    user.setT_26A(T_26A);
                    user.setxT_26(xT_26);
                    user.setxT_130(xT_130);
                    user.setxT_133(xT_133);
                    user.setxT_134(xT_134);
                    user.setct_26(ct_26);
                    user.setT_26_T(T_26_T);
                    user.setbt_1(bt_1);
                    user.setm1930(m1930);
                    user.setbt_2(bt_2);
                    user.setbt_2_PP(bt_2_PP);
                    user.setbt_2_P(bt_2_P);
                    user.setbt_2_PY(bt_2_PY);
                    user.setbt_2_PY_B_SH_u(bt_2_PY);
                    user.setbt_2_H(bt_2_H);
                    user.setbt_2_S(bt_2_S);
                    user.setbt_2_IS(bt_2_IS);
                    user.setbt_3(bt_3);
                    user.setbt_4(bt_4);
                    user.setbt_5(bt_5);
                    user.setbt_5_A(bt_5_A);
                    user.setbt_5_PT(bt_5_PT);
                    user.setbt_5_IS(bt_5_IS);
                    user.setbt_5_B_2(bt_5_B_2);
                    user.setxbt_5(xbt_5);
                    user.setrbt_5(rbt_5);
                    user.setbt_5_Px(bt_5_PX);
                    database.child(emailString).setValue(user);
                }
```

Comment: That for loop over `getChildren()` in your first code block looks like it isn't doing anything. Which in itself is good, as you don't need to loop over `getChildren()` here as you're loading one specific snapshot already.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, i removed for loop, but nothing happened. What i need to do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file to have a better view. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, show us the code that was changed according to Frank's suggestion.

Comment: @AlexMamo, i added database structure and i just removed for-each loop

Comment: The structure in my opinion is incomplete, that's why I asked you to add it again.

Comment: So that's it. you only have a single child inside your entire database, right? And you want to read the value of `battles` and `email`, correct?

Comment: @AlexMamo, it is like an example. I have more then 500 variables which i need to read, by the way, i have string and int variables, so yes, i need to read it

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you need. If you say you have multiple children, please show us a complete structure. Do you need to query all children or only one, the one your answer?

Comment: @AlexMamo, i have only one child, i added photo

Comment: Ok, I see now. I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to read the values of `battles` and `email`, first of all, there is no need to attach a persistent listener. You can only call [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()) and read the values. Besides that, since there is a single child in your database, there is no need to iterate over the DataSnapshot object. So in code, it will be as simple as:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
db.child("mail@gmailcom").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            long battles = snapshot.child("battles").getValue(Long.class);
            String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", battles + "/" + email);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
5000/mail@gmailcom
```

Comment: i tryed, but nothing happaned. I added `db.child(email).get().` and nothing happened. also i tryed to make this: `db.child("mail@mailcom").get().` 
Also i tryed to read without child group, nothing happened.
By the way LogCat is empty

Comment: None of those attempts will work. Please use the solution in my answer, not any other code. So give it a try and tel me if it works.

Comment: It did't work I edted qustion and added more data and code, that we didn't go around to about

Comment: I have added a call to `.child("mail@gmailcom")`. See my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: In Profiler menu i checked that when i pressed button with load data from db it just ignored pressing because speed of network stay being on zero, but when i send data to db it have 12mb/sec.
in database inspectot i saw this error `Database Inspector: Error reading Sqlite database: Database 'LiveSqliteDatabaseId(path=/data/data/com.ccs.example/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db, name=google_app_measurement_local.db, connectionId=1) not found`
is this error which i need to fix?

Comment: Did you try the code in my updated answer?

Comment: Yes, i tryed, but it ignored

Comment: "it ignored" doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: well... When i press the button, profiler show me that i touched this button, but speed of network stayed zero so in my opinion that something trouble in button, because it did't connected to db?

Comment: You should debug yourself and see why is that happening. If you solve the issue using my solution, please let me know.